# Why is the Vector array printing the memory addresses instead of the array values and why do I get an access violation in my sorting functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, vector

I'm developing a program that reads text files and stores the words in an array that can be sorted and then searched through. I've already tried using a dynamically allocated array to place the words into from the text files, but all I get is string cannot be read error from my getline (this doesn't happen when I use vectors). When I try to print out the vector array to see what is being passed through to my sorting functions, it prints out the memory addresses of the array and not the values stored in the array.

I also get a read access violation in my sorting functions at certain points in the function after I've pass the vector arrays to them and I don't understand why. I do show in the code where the problem is accruing. Please note that I'm very new to coding and this program is far from complete. I'm including all of the code I have done so far because if I just show the problem areas I don't think it will be understandable why I'm having these errors. Any help is appreciated thank you.

```
 #include "flore0900header.h"

int main()
{
    string name;
    int num = 0, num2 = 0, count = 0;
    vector<string> word; //to pass vector array to another function

    cout << "Hello. Enter your name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Welcome " << name << " This program lets you test 5 different sorting algorithms using texts files" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Which text file would you like to search?" << endl;
    cout << "=========================================" << endl;
    cout << "1. The Blue Hotel" << endl;
    cout << "2. 20,000 Leagues Under the Sea" << endl;
    cout << "3. A Tale of Two Cities" << endl;
    cin >> num;

    count = text_select(num);
    catch_array(&word); //passing vector array by reference. '&' is there because it won't work otherwise
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Which sorting algorithems would you like to use?" << endl;
    cout << "========================================" << endl;
    cout << "1. Selection" << endl;
    cout << "2. Bubble" << endl;
    cout << "3. Insertion" << endl;
    cout << "4. Merge" << endl;
    cout << "5. Quick" << endl;
    cin >> num; cin >> num2;

    sort_select(num, &word, count);//'&' is there because it won't work otherwise
    sort_select(num2, &word, count);//'&' is there because it won't work otherwise

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Ok! Running algorithms..........." << endl;
}
```

the header file

```
#ifndef FLORE0900HEADER_H
#define FLORE0900HEADER_H

#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>
/* some of the includes are not needed, I haven't removed the un-needed ones yet*/

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

void selection_sort(vector<string> a[], int size);
void bubble_sort(vector<string> a[], int size);
void insertion_sort(vector<string> a[], int size);
void merge_sort(vector<string> a[], int from, int to);
void quick_sort(vector<string> a[], int from, int to);
int text_select(int num);
void sort_select(int num, vector<string> a[], int size);
vector<string> catch_array(vector<string> a[]);
void merge(vector<string> a[], int from, int mid, int to);
int min_position(vector<string> a[], int from, int to);
int partition(vector<string> a[], int from, int to);
void swap(int& x, int& y);
void print(vector<string> a[], int size);

#endif
```

text_select function file

```
#include "flore0900header.h"
//#include <vector>

int text_select(int num)
{
    int count = 0;
    vector<string> words(100000);
    //vector<string>* word2 = new vector<string>[count];
    
    std::ifstream infile;

    if (num == 1)
    {
        infile.open("blue_hotel.txt");
        if (infile.is_open())
        {
            cout << "file is open" << endl;
            getline(infile, words[count]);//string read error when using not using vector
            while (!infile.eof())
            {
                infile >> words[count];
                count++;
                infile.ignore();
                getline(infile, words[count]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "file didn't open" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else if (num == 2)
    {
        infile.open("2under.txt");
        if (infile.is_open())
        {
            cout << "file is open" << endl;
            getline(infile, words[count]);
            while (!infile.eof())
            {
                infile >> words[count];
                count++;
                infile.ignore();
                getline(infile, words[count]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "file didn't open" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else if (num == 3)
    {
        infile.open("2city10.txt");
        if (infile.is_open())
        {
            cout << "file is open" << endl;
            getline(infile, words[count]);
            while (!infile.eof())
            {
                infile >> words[count];
                count++;
                infile.ignore();
                getline(infile, words[count]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "file didn't open" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "not a valid choice try again" << endl;
    infile.close();
    catch_array(&words);//if I don't use '&' the vector won't pass through 
    return count;
}

vector<string> catch_array(vector<string> a[])
{
     return *a;//if I don't put '*' before the 'a' I get an error
}
```

sort_select file

```
#include "flore0900header.h"

void sort_select(int num, vector<string> a[], int size)
{
    int from = 0;

    if (num == 1)
    {
        selection_sort(a, size);
    }
    else if (num == 2)
    {
        bubble_sort(a, size);
    }
    else if (num == 3)
    {
        insertion_sort(a, size);
    }
    else if (num == 4)
    {
        merge_sort(a, from, size);
    }
    else if (num == 5)
    {
        quick_sort(a, from, size);
    }
    else
        cout << "not a valid pick try again" << endl;
}
```

selection_sort file

```
#include "flore0900header.h"

void selection_sort(vector<string> a[], int size)
{
    int next;
    for (next = 0; next < size - 1; next++)
    {
        print(a, size);//to see what is being passed to the function
        int min_pos = min_position(a, next, size - 1);
        swap(a[next], a[min_pos]);
    }
}

int min_position(vector<string> a[], int from, int to)
{
    int min_pos = from;
    for (int i = from + 1; i <= to; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[min_pos])//read access violation happens here
        {
            min_pos = i;
        }
    }
    return min_pos;
}

void print(vector<string> a[], int size)
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << &a[i] << " ";//is printing memory locations instead of values
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

bubble_sort file

```
#include "flore0900header.h"

void bubble_sort(vector<string> a[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) //loop for recording no# of iteration needed to complete the sorting
    {
        int flagForSwap = 0; //creates a flag variable that accounts for wheather the swap function is called at all

        //loop for counting comparisons
        for (int j = 0; j < size - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) //(read access violation happens here) compare adjacent array elements
            {
                swap(a[j], a[j + 1]); //completes the swap
                flagForSwap = 1; // flag to 1 if swap is used
            }
        }

        if (flagForSwap == 0) //breaks the iteration loop if inputed array is already sorted and no swap is needed
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void swap(int& x, int& y)
{
    int temp = x; //creates a temp variable to store the value of the current element
    x = y; // change the value of the current element to next element
    y = temp; //assigns the value of temp to next element
}
```

insertion_sort file

```
#include "flore0900header.h"

void insertion_sort(vector<string> a[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        vector<string> next = a[i];//read access violation happens here
        int j = i;
        while (j > 0 && a[j - 1] > next)
        {
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        a[j] = next;
    }
}
```

merge_sort file

```
#include "flore0900header.h"

void merge_sort(vector<string> a[], int from, int to)
{
    if (from == to)
    {
        return;
    }
    int mid = (from + to) / 2;
    merge_sort(a, from, mid);
    merge_sort(a, mid + 1, to);
    merge(a, from, mid, to);
}

void merge(vector<string> a[], int from, int mid, int to)
{
    int n = to - from + 1;
    vector<string>* b = new vector<string>[n];
    int i1 = from;
    int i2 = mid + 1;
    int j = 0;
    while (i1 <= mid && i2 <= to)
    {
        if (a[i1] < a[i2])//read access violation happens here
        {
            b[j] = a[i1];
            i1++;
        }
        else
        {
            b[j] = a[i2];
            i2++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    while (i1 <= mid)
    {
        b[j] = a[i1];
        i1++;
        j++;
    }
    while (i2 <= to)
    {
        b[j] = a[i2];
        i2++;
        j++;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        a[from + j] = b[j];
    }
    delete[] b;
}
```

quick_sort file

```
#include "flore0900header.h"

void quick_sort(vector<string> a[], int from, int to)
{
    if (from >= to)
    {
        return;
    }
    int p = partition(a, from, to);
    quick_sort(a, from, p);
    quick_sort(a, p + 1, to);
}

int partition(vector<string> a[], int from, int to)
{
    vector<string> pivot = a[from];
    int i = from - 1;
    int j = to + 1;
    while (i < j)
    {
        i++;
        while (a[i] < pivot)//read access violation happens here
        {
            i++;
        }
        j--;
        while (a[j] > pivot)
        {
            j--;
        }
        if (i < j)
        {
            swap(a[i], a[j]);
        }
    }
    return j;
}
```

Comment: Holy mother of code! Please condense your code down to a [mre]. 
It's a pain to read line after line of irrelevant code. 
The exercise of creating a MRE forces you to look at your code and try to isolate the problem, which can often help you figure out the issue without even having to ask on SO. Since you're new here, please also take the [tour], and read [ask] and [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: _"sort_select(num, &word, count);//'&' is there because it won't work otherwise"_ Programming by guessing doesn't work.

Comment: Why does `sort_select` take an array of vectors?

Comment: This is _way_ too much code for this site. You'll need to narrow down your problem to something specific, then show us in the form of a [mcve]. Good luck!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz OP probably didn't see the vector change as they passed it by value, so added a `&` to pass a pointer instead... then got a compilation error and decided to add `[]`. Which is wrong. As I say, programming by guessing.

Comment: The fact that people bothered to look through all that unrelated code speaks to some real boredom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "a vector array".

You *can* have arrays of vectors, but *you don't*.

Yet, here, your function is written as if it does:

```
int partition(vector<string> a[], int from, int to)
//                            ^^
```

I imagine this was done because, before you added the `[]` here and the `&` there, your functions appeared not to do anything.

That was because you were passing the vector *by value*, so changes in the function were made to a copy, and thus not reflected in the calling scope.

Your changes allowed the code to compile, and possibly even "work" in some obscure cases, but only by chance; the `[INDEX]` syntax is shared between vectors and arrays. But you don't have an array, so pretending to the function that you do is wrong. Most of your accesses go out of bounds.

Also note that if you didn't have a `bool operator<(const vector<string>&, const vector<string>&)` defined somewhere, it *wouldn't* compile.

Anyway, the solution to use your one vector is simple:

1. Get rid of that `[]`
2. Get rid of that `&`
3. Change what is now `vector<string>` into `vector<string>&`. That `&` means "take a reference".

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out. I didn't realize I was using the syntax wrong, since the compiler didn't complain until after I compiled the code to check if it was working properly. That change fixed the issue I was having.

Comment: It would be rude not to upvote this for effort alone (and it's the correct answer of course).